# How to mock event and event handler for node.js module?

Tags: jestjs

Here is my function

```js
async function remoteCSVToJSON<T>(url: string, options: csv.ConverterOptions) {
  const defaultOptions = {
    noheader: false,
    delimiter: ',',
    workerNum: os.cpus().length,
  };
  const finalOptions = defaultsDeep(options, defaultOptions);
  const datas: T[] = [];
  return new Promise<T[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(url).then(res => {
      csv(finalOptions)
        .fromString(res)
        .on('json', (jsonObj: T) => datas.push(jsonObj))
        .on('error', err => reject(err))
        .on('end', () => {
          logger.info('convert csv to json done');
          resolve(datas);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

I can mock `fromString` for `csvtojson` module like this:

```js
jest.mock('csvtojson', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    fromString: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

But how do I mock the `.on(event)` method and event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import request from 'request-promise';
import csv from 'csvtojson';
import os from 'os';
import { defaultsDeep } from 'lodash';

export async function remoteCSVToJSON<T>(url: string, options: any) {
  const defaultOptions = {
    noheader: false,
    delimiter: ',',
    workerNum: os.cpus().length
  };
  const finalOptions = defaultsDeep(options, defaultOptions);
  const datas: T[] = [];
  return new Promise<T[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(url).then(res => {
      csv(finalOptions)
        .fromString(res)
        .on('json', (jsonObj: T) => datas.push(jsonObj))
        .on('error', err => reject(err))
        .on('end', () => {
          console.info('convert csv to json done');
          resolve(datas);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import request from 'request-promise';
import csv from 'csvtojson';
import os from 'os';
import { remoteCSVToJSON } from './';

jest.mock('csvtojson', () => {
  const mCsv = {
    on: jest.fn(),
    fromString: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mCsv);
});

jest.mock('request-promise', () => {
  return {
    get: jest.fn()
  };
});

describe('remoteCSVToJSON', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should request and convert csv to json', async () => {
    const events: any = {};
    csv()
      .fromString()
      .on.mockImplementation(function(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
        const [event, handler] = args;
        events[event] = handler;
        return this;
      });
    const mGetResponse = { data: 'fake data' };
    (request.get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof request.get>).mockResolvedValueOnce(mGetResponse);
    const infoSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'info');

    const actualValue = remoteCSVToJSON('url', {});
    const mJsonObj = { id: 1, name: 'mrdulin' };
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(csv)).toBeTruthy();
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    expect(csv).toBeCalledWith({
      noheader: false,
      delimiter: ',',
      workerNum: os.cpus().length
    });
    expect(csv().fromString).toBeCalledWith(mGetResponse);
    events['json'](mJsonObj);
    events['end']();
    await expect(actualValue).resolves.toEqual([mJsonObj]);
    expect(request.get).toBeCalledWith('url');
    expect(infoSpy).toBeCalledWith('convert csv to json done');
  });

  test('should throw error when convert error', async () => {
    const events: any = {};
    csv()
      .fromString()
      .on.mockImplementation(function(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
        const [event, handler] = args;
        events[event] = handler;
        return this;
      });
    const mGetResponse = { data: 'fake data' };
    (request.get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof request.get>).mockResolvedValueOnce(mGetResponse);

    const actualValue = remoteCSVToJSON('url', {});
    const mJsonObj = { id: 1, name: 'mrdulin' };
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(csv)).toBeTruthy();
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    expect(csv).toBeCalledWith({
      noheader: false,
      delimiter: ',',
      workerNum: os.cpus().length
    });
    expect(csv().fromString).toBeCalledWith(mGetResponse);
    events['json'](mJsonObj);
    const mError = new Error('mock error');
    events['error'](mError);
    await expect(actualValue).rejects.toThrowError(mError);
    expect(request.get).toBeCalledWith('url');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57423762/index.spec.ts (6.995s)
  remoteCSVToJSON
    ✓ should request and convert csv to json (16ms)
    ✓ should throw error when convert error (22ms)

  console.info node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    convert csv to json done

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.114s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57423762